# Macro Enable Workbooks Regularly Corrupt when stored in SharePoint Online

Tags: excel, sharepoint

We are seeing a major issue with a template based (macro-enabled) spreadsheet where, for some more than others (as the usage varies across the 258 instances), the workbook is opened to an error 'Can't find project or library' and no changes can then be saved.
Each version of the spreadsheet is stored in it's own specific SharePoint (Online) site, and as it's a macro-enabled workbook, users can only make changes when the file is opened in the Excel app. All users use company supplied laptops with the same version of Windows (10)/Office (365 ProPlus) as they are locked down to a corporate image.
The only way to fix these corrupted file(s) is with an Excel tool I have written that will copy all the data from the corrupted workbook to a clean template, and then re-save the file over the top. Although this doesn't take long to run, it's frustrating for the teams who get this error (some more often than others) and means they have to rely on me having time (and being available/online) to run my 'fix' before they can make any subsequent changes.
We also had this in the previous on-premise version of SharePoint, so it's not specific to the online version, but I have never been able to figure out the cause of these corruptions and feel it's time to attempt to find (and fix, if possible) the underlying cause.
For reference there is a workbook open which initialises a usage log, but there is no on-save event as we found that these would not fire when, in SharePoint 2010, users would simply check a file in and the on-save event would never fire.
Has anyone seen anything similar with Excel macro-enabled workbooks saved to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem and there is some discussion here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/macro-enabled-excel-corrupts-on-save-with-onedrive/edac1890-a4f2-4315-a606-1ee238ce8907

I would suggest making it a practice to zip all excel workbooks before uploading to sharepoint. The problem seems to occur when people open them in O365 excel